# Problem adding objects in Entity Framework, I'm guessing it's a problem with my database model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, database-design

My problem is that I'm trying to add a child entity, but keep running into problems.

Here's my situation:

I have a bunch of Profiles.
Each Profile has a bunch of CategoryPriorities attached to it.
Each CategoryPriorities has one AttributePriority attached to it.

[image]

When I update my model in Visual Studio I get the following:
[image]

I can without any trouble get the following to work:

```
CategoryPriority _categoryPriority = new CategoryPriority();
Profile _profile = DB.GetProfile(ProfileID);
_profile.CategoryPriorities.Add(_categoryPriority);
DB.savechanges()
```

But somehow the following will not work:

```
AttributePriority _attributePriority = new AttributePriority();    
CategoryPriority _categoryPriority = new CategoryPriority();
_categoryPriority.AttributePriorities.Add(_attributePriority);
// Error! There is no option of "Add" or any other operation for the matter.

Profile _profile = DB.GetProfile(ProfileID);
_profile.CategoryPriorities.Add(_categoryPriority);
DB.savechanges()
```

I'm guessing this is due to how the EF model is set up.
Ideally I would like to have an one-to-one between CategoryPriority and AttributePriority tables.

I'll add an image of my model.

Any ideas?
Any help much appreciated!

Edit:
I've added images to my post.

Funny thing is that if I write:

```
Profile _p = new Profile();
```

There is no option of `_p.Add` there either.. obviously I'm missing something..

Edit 2:
Ok, so I got it to work, almost...
I know, not the most aesthetically pleasing code, I'm working on that..

```
Profile _profile = this.GetProfile(this.GetUserID(arrangeattributesviewmodel.ProfileID));

int iter = 0;
foreach (AttributeListForCategory _category in arrangeattributesviewmodel.AllAttributesForCheckBoxList.CategoryAttributeList)
{
iter++;
CategoryPriority _categoryPriority = new CategoryPriority();

_categoryPriority.ProfileID = arrangeattributesviewmodel.ProfileID;
_categoryPriority.CategoryID = _category.CategoryID;
_categoryPriority.CategoryName = _category.CategoryName;
_categoryPriority.CategoryID = _category.CategoryID;
_categoryPriority.CategoryPriorityNR = iter;


AttributePriority _attributePriority = new AttributePriority();
_attributePriority.AttributePriorityString = _category.CompilePriorityString();
_categoryPriority.AttributePriority = _attributePriority;
_profile.CategoryPriorities.Add(_categoryPriority);

db.SaveChanges(); // It fails here with the message below..
}
```

{"A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column. Column: 'CategoryPriorityID'."}

Any ideas?

Edit 3:
Solved it!

I had to instanciate an AttributePriority in my CategoryPriority...

Comment: Is `AttributePriorities` collection in `CategoryPriority` entity?  You should show your model and also CREATE scripts of your tables.

Comment: I think so, kind of new to EF. I will add images of my database model as soon I can (need another 2 reputation scores I think)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your relation between `CategoryPriority` and `AttributePriority` is 1:0..1 so there is not `Add` method. You simply call:

```
_categoryPriority.AttributePriority = attributePriority;
```

Btw. how is it possible that your entity define `AttributePriority` but your code uses `AttributePriorities`? It should not compile.

Comment: That was a typo..
Thanks for your help!
Have another problem though, updating my question...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have foreign keys set up correctly and then regenerate your model.